# ~, and not continue on the same path. (Is the 'on' here a preposition?)

Tags: prepositions

> Obama says he wants American space exploration to leap into the future, and not continue **on** the same path.

Is the 'on' here a preposition?

Comment: This can be googled. "continue on the same"

Comment: Google does not tell me if it's a preposition or not.

Comment: How is this not a dupe of [this question of yours](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/325008/he-continued-on-his-way-on-is-a-preposition-or-adverb/325025#325025)?

Comment: Yes, For me, It's a preposition. It implies you should choose another path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [He continued on his way. ('on' is a preposition or adverb?)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/325008/he-continued-on-his-way-on-is-a-preposition-or-adverb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a preposition! Whether it's a metaphorical path or a real physical path.